# what actions would you take before you expose the you internal wiki to the world wide?

Tags: security, wiki

I've been asked to expose our internal wiki to the world wide, which actions would you recommend me to take to secure the wiki from potential attacks? the wiki software is mindtouch.

few points I already raised:

- secure it with ssl to prevent M.I.D attacks
- put captcha mechanism on the login page for brute force attacks - is someone familiar with such plugin for mindtouch?
- another password on apache level.
- unfortunately VPN is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use modsecurity for apache, its an application firewall for HTTP, it protects against all kinds of attacks. its uses a signature/rule base mechanism and you can write your own rules.

http://www.modsecurity.org/projects/modsecurity/apache/

Answer (score 2):

Additional to captcha you can:

1.stopforumspam - http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Combating_spam

2.Wikimedia SpamBlacklist extension -http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SpamBlacklist

3.Restrict editing - allow auth users only

Answer (score 0):

1. install all available patches to the wiki. and subscribe to the wiki dev list to get notified on patches or security holes.
2. harden all involved components that this wiki uses... e.g mysql
3. double check the wiki contend for internal network/server information :-) and remove it.